# How to switch of headsepline in KOMA Script for selfdefined pagestyle

Tags: header-footer, koma-script

I have a document where I want to have the headsepline on in general but switch it off for chapters. The following MWE works but the used option `\setheadsepline{0ex}` is deprecated.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[manualmark,headsepline,footsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\lehead{left even}
\cehead{center even}
\rehead{right even}

\lohead{left odd}
\cohead{center odd}
\rohead{right odd}

\newpairofpagestyles[scrheadings]{chapter}{%
\lehead*{}%
\cehead*{useless text}%
\cohead*{usefull text}%
\rohead*{}%
\setheadsepline{0ex}}

\renewcommand*\chapterpagestyle{chapter}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

The log says:

```
Package scrlayer-scrpage Warning: Command deprecated!
(scrlayer-scrpage)                Usage of `\setheadtopline', `\setheadsepline',

(scrlayer-scrpage)                `\setfootsepline', and `\setfootbotline'
(scrlayer-scrpage)                became deprecated with scrlayer-scrpage.
(scrlayer-scrpage)                You should use KOMA-Script options
(scrlayer-scrpage)                `headsepline', `headtopline', `footsepline',
(scrlayer-scrpage)                or `footbotline' with values
(scrlayer-scrpage)                `<line thickness>:<line length>' to setup
(scrlayer-scrpage)                the line length and thickness, and
(scrlayer-scrpage)                `\setkomafont' or `\addtokomafont' to
(scrlayer-scrpage)                setup the colour on input line 23.
```

I also found hints in the documentation that I can use the option `headsepline=false` to switch it off for a pagestyle. But where do I pass that option?

Comment: You are thinking too complicated i think and use the wrong interface (the one for experienced users). Use `\cehead[useful text]{center even}`  and `\cohead[useless text]{center odd}`. Avoid the generation f a new page style/

Comment: You can use `\KOMAoption{headsepline}{false}` instead of the current line, that sets the width to zero and generates the warning.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I generate new pagestyles because in my actual document I want different styles for the toc, chapters and "normal" pages. Thus I have three styles and the interface you suggested seems to only support two.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use \KOMAoptions in the definition

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[manualmark,headsepline,footsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\lehead{left even}
\cehead{center even}
\rehead{right even}

\lohead{left odd}
\cohead{center odd}
\rohead{right odd}

\newpairofpagestyles[scrheadings]{chapter}{%
\KOMAoptions{headsepline=false}%
\lehead*{}%
\cehead*{useless text}%
\cohead*{usefull text}%
\rohead*{}%
}

\renewcommand*\chapterpagestyle{chapter}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

But I'm not sure if declaring a new paired pagestyle is the way to go. Why don't you redefine the plain style?

Comment: Thanks! I'm also not sure if paired pagestyles is the way to go. :D I had another look at the manual. Seems like I didn't understand their potential yet. I will look more closely into this in the future.

Comment: Could you please indicate how to redefine plain style? I am straggling with KOMA-Script documentation since yesterday to reimplement what i had implemented with `fancyhdr`. KOMA-Script documentation is amazing: it does not contain a single usage example of `\newpagestyle`, neither of `\newpairofpagestyles`.

Answer (score 3):

If you need different styles for TOC, chapter pages and normal pages, you can also use the plain style for your chapter pages with

```
\lehead{left even}
\cehead[useless text]{center even}
\rehead*{right even}

\lohead*{left odd}
\cohead[usefull text]{center odd}
\rohead{right odd}
```

and change the header and footer in TOC by

```
\BeforeTOCHead[toc]{%
    \clearpage
    \KOMAoptions{plainfootsepline=false}%
    \lehead[]{left even in toc}%
    \cehead[]{center even in toc}%
    \rehead[]{right even in toc}%
%
    \lohead[]{left odd in toc}%
    \cohead[]{center odd in toc}%
    \rohead[right on odd toc start page]{right odd in toc}%
}
\AfterStartingTOC[toc]{\clearpage}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[
    manualmark,
    headsepline,
    footsepline,
    plainfootsepline% added to get a footline on plain pages
]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{microtype}

\lehead{left even}
\cehead[useless text]{center even}
\rehead*{right even}

\lohead*{left odd}
\cohead[usefull text]{center odd}
\rohead{right odd}

\BeforeTOCHead[toc]{%
    \clearpage
    \KOMAoptions{plainfootsepline=false}%
    \lehead[]{left even in toc}%
    \cehead[]{center even in toc}%
    \rehead[]{right even in toc}%
%
    \lohead[]{left odd in toc}%
    \cohead[]{center odd in toc}%
    \rohead[right on odd toc start page]{right odd in toc}%
}
\AfterStartingTOC[toc]{\clearpage}

\begin{document}
\addchap{Introduction}
\Blindtext
\tableofcontents
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

You could also use something like

```
\BeforeTOCHead{%
    \clearpage
    \KOMAoptions{automark}%
    \clearpairofpagestyles
    \chead[plain page in toc]{}%
    \ohead{\headmark}%
    \ofoot*{\pagemark}%
}
\AfterStartingTOC{\clearpage}
```

to use `automark` in TOC, LOT and LOF.